# Interpreting Postfix Scheme in python, multiple lambda functions

Tags: python, lambda, scheme

I've been tasked with created a program in python that interprets Scheme written in post-fix notation. Right now I'm attempting to interpret the "reverse Scheme" program

```
(abs ((n) (0 n ((n 0 >) + - if)) lambda) define)
(f ((n) (n 2 *) lambda) define)
((2 f) abs)
```

which is

```
(define abs (lambda (n) ((if (> n 0) + - ) 0 n )))
(define f (lambda (n) (* n 2 )))
(abs (f 2))
```

in "regular" scheme.

In order to handle lambda functions in the code, I first parse over the code in the parseLambda function, and if I find any, I package the function into a single object and put it back in the input string, where the entire program is evaluated in evaluateExpression.

The program seems to be putting both the "abs" function and the "f" function in their respective single objects properly, and evaluateExpression appear to be defining both f and abs properly, but the first time f is called, it executes the abs function instead. I'm almost certain the problem has something to do with the line

```
inputList.insert(i - j, lambda *x: evaluateExpression(lambdaFunctionList, functionList, localVariableList, *x))
```

line, and that the problem has to do with pointers somehow.

Any idea what could be causing this problem?

```
import fileinput
import re
import string

def parseLambda (inputList, functionList): # position is the spot in inputList right before        'lambda', takes the lambda function out and replaces it with a named version of itself.
i = -1
while (i < len(inputList) - 1 ): # i will stop at the point where the lambda function is, remove the lambda keyword, the lambda function, and all its variables, and replace with an object that's a lambda function.
    i = i + 1
    if inputList[i] == 'lambda':
        lambdaFunctionList = []
        j = -1
        balancedParen = 0
        inputToken = ""
        while (inputToken != '(' or balancedParen != 0):
            j = j + 1
            inputToken = inputList.pop(i - j)
            if (inputToken == ')'):
                balancedParen = balancedParen + 1
            if (inputToken == '('):
                balancedParen = balancedParen - 1
            if (inputToken != 'lambda'):
                lambdaFunctionList.insert(0, inputToken)
        inputList.pop(i - j) # gets extra parentheses out
        inputToken = ""
        localVariableList = []
        while (inputToken != '('):
            j = j + 1
            inputToken = inputList.pop(i - j)
            if (inputToken != '(' and inputToken != ')' and inputToken != ','):
                localVariableList.append(inputToken)
        j = j + 1 # gets extra parentheses out
        inputList.pop(i - j)
        inputList.insert(i - j, lambda *x: evaluateExpression(lambdaFunctionList, functionList, localVariableList, *x))
        i = i - j


def evaluateExpression(inputList, functionList, localVariableList, localVariableValues):
counter = 0
for i in localVariableList:
    if (isinstance(localVariableValues, list)):
        functionList['define'](localVariableValues[counter],i)
    else:
        functionList['define'](localVariableValues,i)
    counter = counter + 1

parameterList = []
while (len(inputList) != 0):
    inputValue = inputList.pop()
    if inputValue == '(':
        break
    elif inputValue == ')':
        valueToAdd = evaluateExpression(inputList, functionList, localVariableList, localVariableValues)
        if valueToAdd != None:
            parameterList.append(valueToAdd)
    else:
        parameterList.append(inputValue)
functionName = ""
functionName = parameterList.pop(0)
parameterList2 = []
for i in parameterList:
    if not (isinstance(i, list)) and functionName != 'if' and i in functionList:
        parameterList2.append(functionList[i])
    else:
        parameterList2.append(i)
else:
    if functionName in functionList:
        return functionList[functionName](*parameterList2)
    elif len(parameterList2) > 1:
        return parameterList2
    else:
        return functionName

#main method
schemeProgram = ""
for line in open("SchemeProgram.txt"):#Open input from a file
schemeProgram = line + schemeProgram
schemeProgram = re.sub('\(', ' ( ', schemeProgram)# replace all ( and ) with " ( " and " ) " to    make space-delimited parsing possible.
schemeProgram = re.sub('\)', ' ) ', schemeProgram)
# Construct the dictionary of base functions, which will be passed into the program evaluator.
functionList = {}
functionList['+'] = lambda x, y: int(y) + int(x) # + function
functionList['-'] = lambda x, y: int(y) - int(x) # - function
functionList['*'] = lambda x, y: int(y) * int(x) # * function
functionList['/'] = lambda x, y: int(y) / int(x) # / function
functionList['define'] = lambda x, y: defineCallBack(y, x)
def defineCallBack (x, y):
    functionList[str(x)] = y
functionList['if'] = lambda x, y, z: y if z else x
functionList['<'] = lambda x, y: True if (y < x) else False
functionList['>'] = lambda x, y: True if (y > x) else False
inputList = schemeProgram.split()
parseLambda(inputList, functionList)# Remove all lambda functions and replace them with the value in functionList.
print evaluateExpression(inputList, functionList, [], [])
fileinput.close()
```

Comment: This code won't even compile, and it's far from being a [verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but I can throw out a quick guess based on your guess: you're probably either closing over something when you actually wanted a copy of the value, or reusing some list or other mutable value instead of creating a new one for each lambda.

Comment: An example of postfix notation is the stack based RPN implementation used on HP calculators. It might be worth considering that `define` and `lambda` and `if` are all special forms in Lisp, not functions. That is they expand into more Lisp code rather than returning a value directly. Finally, I would suggest passing parameters in strict reverse order e.g. end with `...abs) define)` rather than making an arbitrary change [does the true or false condition come first with the reversed `if`?]

Comment: @benrudgers, don't forget about primitives.